# Deactivate unused session id in database?

Tags: authentication, security, session-cookies, form-authentication

I have a website that has form authentication:

1) User logs in with choice of whether to keep him logged in or not.

2) Server generates token, saves it to the database and sends a token cookie to the browser.

Note that when the user chooses not to keep logged in, when he closes his browser, the token cookie will expire, and if the user chooses to keep logged in, the token cookie will expire a year after he logged in.

3) When the user logs out, the server will deactivate the token saved in the database and will delete the token cookie in the browser.

The problem is, if the user chooses not keep logged in, if he closes his browser, the token cookie will expire but the token saved in a database will not be deactivated - the server will not know if the user closes his browser.

How am I going to deactivate unused token in my database?

Answer (score 0):

Persisting an entire session on the server side just to remember the login details is not common practice. I recommend following facebook/google's design: if the user wishes the browser to "remember him", generate some random-secure "access token" cookie that is persisted in the user table as the last valid access token for that user. Then, when the browser accesses the website again, it sends that cookie and the server can check if it matches any of the existing (valid) access tokens, and thus login the user.

Comment: I generate session id (token), save it to database and send it as cookie into the browser. By the time the user visits my website, I checked his session cookie and find a match in my database. How is mine different from Google's or Facebook's?

Comment: you also need to write some expiration timestamp in your db, for the token, and test it during login. You do not need to remove tokens from the db, simply keep the last one there (one per user). Of course, you don't need to create tokens for anonymous sessions.... otherwise your db will explode :)